# How to make a commandline statusbar that is 'updated' in Python

Tags: python, terminal

I don't know the right terms, so it is a bit hard to search how I can achieve this.

Commandline programs normally just print lines of text. Sometimes however, the text is updated. Good examples are `git pull` or `wget`.

As example:

```
[>   ]  25%
[->  ]  50%
[--> ]  75%
[--->] 100%
```

But then on the same line changing over time.

How can I make this kind of thing in Python? It doesn't have to be more complicated than this, I just want to make status bars...

(I want this to work at least on Ubuntu, but cross-platform is the nicest.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [the progressbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2) package?

Comment: progressbar was not updated since 2018. I would rather recommend [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) which is still actively developed and much more capable.

Answer (score 3):

The magic is in `\r` character, a.k.a. carriage return, a.k.a. go back to the beginning of the current line.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time    

for i in xrange(1, 100):
    print('[{0:10}]'.format('-' * (i / 10)), end = '\r')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

There are also more advanced ways to manage the output to the console (through Console API on Windows, or ANSI escape codes) — they allow you to freely move the cursor and change text attributes like colour.

Answer (score 0):

print "progress text\r",

Notice the trailing comma which suppresses new line.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything on my Bash terminal

Comment: @Peter Smit:  Interesting.  It works fine on Windows.  I don't know why it wouldn't work on Bash unless it just doesn't support the carriage return character...

Answer (score 0):

This Code also works in Google Colab

```
import time
for i in range(1, 101):
    print('-'  , end = ' ')
    print(i  , end = ' ')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('\r',end = ' ')
print('-'  , end = ' ')
print(i  , end = ' ')
```